# (vim profiling) VIM 256 colors mode, laggy php files

Tags: vim, profiling, performance, lag, 256color

I'm using 256-colors theme in vim (set t_Co=256) and all php files opens about 8 seconds.

- It's my local dual-core machine
- It doesn't depend on color scheme I used (zenburn, wombat, wombat256)
- HTML, Python, JS or every else files opens momentary
- It takes about 8 sec even to create new php files (:o newfile.php)
- I've setting up my terminal [correctly](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/256_colors_in_vim)
- Everything fine if I'm using 16 colors (set t_Co=16)

I really want to use 256-colors mode, it looks much prettier, but I can't get rid of this lags.

Comment: do you have the latest version? I has having delays when using versions after 7.2 (but before 7.3).

Comment: yep, I have lags on 7.3 & 7.2, it strange, but gVim 7.2 works fine

Comment: Try doing `vim -c 'set verbosefile=./vim.log verbose=12' -c 'o newfile.php' -c 'set verbose=0' -c 'qa!'`, then `gvim -c 'set verbosefile=./gvim.log verbose=12' -c 'o newfile.php' -c 'set verbose=0' -c 'qa!'`, then `diff ./vim.log ./gvim.log`. If there are any significant differencies (other than changed script numbers), paste both files somewhere. If not, try doing this with `verbose=15`. Or do this not with gvim, but with vim with `t_Co=16` (or with any other configuration which does not cause troubles).

Comment: If after the previous step you have not found what causes trouble, try doing `vim -c 'profile start ./vim.profile' -c 'profile func *' -c 'profile file *' -c 'o newfile.php' -c 'qa!'`, a table at the end of file `./vim.profile` should give you information, about the function that caused trouble.

Comment: Many thanks, I found, that problem was caused by css highlight script by Chris Yip (http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3220). After I delete it, everything works fine.

Comment: @andrew go ahead and answer your own question.  Then you can select it as the correct answer.  Seems a bit odd, but that's the accepted method of resolving self-answered questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right way to find what cause performance problems in VIM is to profile it or check debug output (optionally - comparing with vim setup without troubles).

Comparing debug output:

```
vim -c 'set verbosefile=./vim1.log verbose=12' -c 'command that causes problem' -c 'qa!'
vim -c 'set verbosefile=./vim2.log verbose=12' -c 'qa!'
diff ./vim1.log ./vim2.log
```

In some cases you can also increase verbose level up to 15

Profiling:

```
vim -c 'profile start ./vim.profile' -c 'profile func *' -c 'profile file *' -c 'command that causes problem' -c 'qa!'
```